# UIPanGestureRecognizer overlaps UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` attached to it. 
I also have an object within the `UIView` that has multiple `UISwipeGestureRecognizers`.

The `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and the `UISwipeGestureRecognizers` associated with the object overlap.

Is there any way to make the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` totally ignore a certain area of the `UIView` or make the object's `UISwipeGestureRecognizers` take precedence and override the `UIView's` `UIPanGestureRecognizer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem using this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
      if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && gestureRecognizer == recognizer) return NO;
      return YES;
}
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @MikeS

Answer (score 4):

What you want is...

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
     if(gestureRecognizer == myPanGesture) return NO;

     return YES;
}
```

Or a similar usage of that delegate method.  It is part of the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol.  This would allow you to not recognize the panning if you are swiping.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I noticed in the documentation for that method it says "...returning NO is not guaranteed to prevent simultaneous recognition, as the other gesture's delegate may return YES". Is there something I should be doing different with my delegates?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the answers, which helped me with my issue.

**I just want to share my solution, because it can be helpful:**

```
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
NSLog2(@"Gesture on Class %@ tag %i", [touch.view class], touch.view.tag);////////

if (touch.view.tag == kTagToIgnoreGestures){
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

I defined a **kTagToIgnoreGestures** which is tag of views that should ignore gestures. 
This way I can have 2 subviews in a view with UIGestureRecognizer, that only one of them will be effected by gestures.

Hope it helps. Shefy